# R save and loads dataframes

Tags: r

I saved the data frame using this command
save(countrydata,file="data.Rda") 
and load it using this command 
load("data.Rda") 
but I do not see the table with the data I have created

Comment: `x <- 1:10;save(x, file = "test.Rda");rm(x);load("test.Rda");ls()` works for me, although I would save it as `*.RData`.

Comment: How are you "looking" for the table? Did you run `ls()`?

Answer (score 2):

Saving a single data.frame with `save` can be confusing because `load` adds the data.frame (and any other objects in the file) into the `parent.frame()` from which `load` is called. ([See Hadley's chapter on environments](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html) in case this terminology is confusing.) It does this invisibly (i.e., it doesn't explicitly tell you that the objects have been loaded). You have to look for them explicitly using `ls()`.

Roman's example (in comment) demonstrates this nicely:

```
x <- 1:10
save(x, file = "test.Rda")
rm(x)
load("test.Rda")
ls()
## [1] "x"
```

You can also avoid this confusion by loading objects into an environment other than the default using the `envir` argument to `load`:

```
e <- new.env()
load("test.Rda", envir = e)
ls()
## [1] "e"
ls(envir = e)
## [1] "x"
```

This keeps it out of your global workspace (and thus prevents `load` from overwriting existing objects).

You might also want to look at the `saveRDS` function, which is designed for saving single objects:

```
saveRDS(x, file = "test.Rda")
```

This will save the object by itself. You can then load it using `readRDS`, which has a return value equivalent to the object:

```
readRDS("test.Rda")
## [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```